# Transparent image overlay Mapbox GL JS

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl

I want to draw a circle around an object in Mapbox GL JS, but it does not seem to support drawing something like that. So I tried creating a PNG with a red circle and a transparent background in Photoshop. But when I load the image on the map, the image loses its transparency.

[image]

The code I used to generate this is:

```
var sourceObj = new mapboxgl.ImageSource({
        url: '/img/circle-red.png',
        coordinates: [
            [-80.425, 46.437],
            [-71.516, 46.437],
            [-71.516, 37.936],
            [-80.425, 37.936]
        ]
});

map.addSource('someimage', sourceObj);

map.addLayer({
    "id": "someimage",
    "source": "someimage",
    "type": "raster"
});
```

Does somebody know how I can achieve an transparent background? Or does someone know an alternative way to draw a circle on the map?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's a year late, but if anyone runs into this again, there is a raster-opacity property on the layer. See https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/adjust-layer-opacity/.

```
map.addLayer({
  "id": "current_image",
  "source": "current_image",
  "type": "raster",
  "paint" : {
    "raster-opacity" : 0.5
  }
});
```

If you're working with an image where you'll know the opacity, that should do the trick!

Comment: opacity does not really do the trick - since it makes the whole image translucent. Is there a proper way to only make the transparent areas transpareant? i.e. look at the alpha channel?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. My current workaround are 8-bit PNGs, but they only have one color that is transparent.